# Unfortunately Application has stopped working libGDX App

Tags: crash, libgdx

When trying to run my application in Android mode it just stops at start. Running it in desktop mode works fine thought. I am using libGDX and Android Studio.

I have no idea what is causing this. It suddenly came just today. Never had any problems running it in Emulator or Phone before.

`01-06 04:37:04.853 2790-2790/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-06 04:37:05.030 2790-2790/com.badlogic.cubocy.android W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.badlogic.cubocy.android-1/lib/x86
01-06 04:37:05.046 2790-2790/com.badlogic.cubocy.android D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-06 04:37:05.046 2790-2790/com.badlogic.cubocy.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.badlogic.cubocy.android, PID: 2790
                                                                           java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
                                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:118)
                                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
                                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.(AndroidApplication.java:61)
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.badlogic.cubocy.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.badlogic.cubocy.android-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgdx.so"
                                                                               at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                               at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:113)
                                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34) 
                                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.(AndroidApplication.java:61) 
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-06 04:37:07.840 2790-2790/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2790 SIG: 9`

Answer (score 0):

- SOLVED -

Reinstalling Android Studio fixed the problem.